# Delete conversation member in a calendar event - MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

After I created a calendar event, participants can start a meeting and then a conversation with each other by chatting. When the meeting ends, I would like to force the participants to leave the chat group so that the chat remains available but they can no longer interact with it (except to download files and read the messages). Is it possible with the actual Microsoft Graph API and the informations inside the response to "Create event" API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? (from MS Teams app it is)

Answer (score 0):

@Federico - From Microsoft Graph API perspective, i never saw an option or a way to force the participants to leave the chat. If you're using Onlinemeeting, then, you can get the meeting start/endtime with startdatetime/enddatetime properties, chatinfo will provide you the chatinfo. Here's the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Alternatively, do you think it is possible to delete the chat? When I create the calendar event, I haven't any informations about it and I don't know how to identify it univocaly (in case there is a MS Graph API that allows me to delete this chat)

Comment: Unfortunately i dont see an option, but i love to see if you come across any related ideas.